# File getting corrupted when uploading with Filezilla

Tags: ftp, notepad++, filezilla

I have been using Filezilla for a long time, but this morning something strange started to happen when i upload from local to server.

When i upload file using Filezilla files are getting curropted.

See original file here: http://pastebin.com/N7r2rkpG

And this is how it looks when i have uploaded: http://pastebin.com/w0RAJZv4

You see the mess start around line 498.

This is from Filezilla upload log:

```
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\mikael\Desktop\OnepageController.php
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 22,797 bytes in 1 second
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers"...
Status: Directory listing of "/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers" successful
```

This problem is only on my desktop. When i do same from notebook on same network all works fine.

Any ideas to what is happening here?

UPDATE: You can see comparison og logs here: diffnow.com/?report=g39mp

Left side is working upload and right side is corrupt

Comment: Can you make sure that the file is being transmitted as text file and not as binary?

Comment: @megamorf It was set to auto but i have tried changing to ASCII but still same problem :(

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903442/files-are-getting-corrupted-via-ftp-client-upload

Comment: The problem you link to is about removing linebreaks. My problem is that it breaks code in middle and start from from beginning again. So not related i am afraid.

Comment: Have you tried if the problem also occurs when you set the transfer mode to binary?

Comment: Yes and compared settings between laptop and desktop without luck. They are identical but only problem on desktop.

Comment: Turn on logging to a file in FileZilla on both machines and attach a log snippet showing the upload.

Comment: @martin i have updated question with link to logs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug to me, either on the client or on the server.

While you rightly claim that this should not be caused by the ascii/text transfer mode (because the problem is not about a line ending), I'd try the binary mode anyway.

Because in the ascii/text mode both the client and server may modify the file, and a bug in the respective code can cause the corruption. In the binary mode, neither side should touch the file, so a chance of the corruption is lower.

---

Note that on Windows, FileZilla should not modify the file on upload even in the ascii/text mode as the FTP text mode format is identical to that of the native Windows text format.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Windows recovery which solved the problem, so it must have been problem local on my machine.

Now i can use next 8 hours to reinstall all programs :(

Thank for helping out.

Comment: Check your drives for errors... File corruption is no finny business.